# How to use onfocusout function in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to call a function as soon as the cursor moves from one text box to next. The function call should be made when a tab is clicked or after the expected entries are entered and moved to next.

Answer (score 100):

Use the [`v-on` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers) to add an event listener for [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) or [`focusout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event) on the `<input>`:

```
v-on:EVENT_NAME="METHOD"
```

*Example:*

```html
<input v-on:blur="handleBlur">
```

Or shorter syntax:

```
@EVENT_NAME="METHOD"
```

*Example:*

```html
<input @blur="handleBlur">
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    handleBlur(e) {
      console.log('blur', e.target.placeholder)
    },
    handleFocusout(e) {
      console.log('focusout', e.target.placeholder)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>blur</legend>
    <input @blur="handleBlur" placeholder="first name">
    <input @blur="handleBlur" placeholder="last name">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>focusout</legend>
    <input @focusout="handleFocusout" placeholder="email">
    <input @focusout="handleFocusout" placeholder="phone">
  </fieldset>
</div>
```