# vuejs event modifier search list process

Tags: vue.js

I'm a vue js newbie, I perform a get operation with the value entered in the search input and if there is a result, I show it in "listShow", if there is no result, I return "listShow" false. no problem so far. only if the user chooses any of the incoming data, I send the "name" searchtext of the incoming data to the input. but if there is no result "listShow false" and click somewhere outside the input
I want to make "newDiv" true. so "inputOutClick" does the job, but when I click on any of the "search" data, "inputOutClick" does not allow this "selecteds()" function to fire.

**And also, is my coding style correct, I'm getting too repetitive.**

1. Is it ok to use search @keyup?
2. Does it make sense to use v-on:focusout?

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        searchText: '',
        listShow: true,
        newDiv:false,
        searcList:[],
    },
   
    methods: {
        inputOutClick() {
            this.listShow = false
        },
        selecteds(list) {
            this.listShow = false;
            this.searchText = list.name;
        },
        
        async search() {
            if (this.searchText !== '') {
                const res = await this.callApi('get', 'search' + '?filter=' + this.searchText)
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    this.searcList = this.getList;
                    if (res.data.length > 0) {
                        this.listShow = true;
                    } else {
                        this.listShow = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                this.listShow = false;
            }
        }

    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                v-model="searchText"
                @keyup="search"
                v-on:focusout="inputOutClick"
                />
            <div v-if="listShow" style="background:red">
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="(list, index) in searcList">
                        <a @click="selecteds(list)">{{ list.name }}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
           <div v-if="newDiv">
           <p>hello</p>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: A thought, perhaps this data being returned is not false, but an empty object, or array, depending on what you have. `res.data.length` might not be zero, but the data in the object is. What's the behavior as seen from the API, or in Postman

Comment: please don't deal with axios data, that's not what I want to do, there is no problem with the data from get, there is no problem with listing. if you read well.

Comment: maybe this will help: `v-on:blur` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52070811/13604954

Comment: no this is not what i want

Comment: Maybe is not working well on input. I found this link. https://codepen.io/autumnwoodberry/pen/NvjJWm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@mousedown.prevent` on the `searchList` entries (where the `click` handler is attached). This prevents the `v-on:focusout` event being fired, if a `searchList` entry is clicked.

```html
<input
  type="text"
  v-model="searchText"
  @keyup="search"
  v-on:focusout="inputOutClick"
/>

<a
  @click="selectEntry(entry)"
  @mousedown.prevent
>
  xxx
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use @mousedown instead of @click.

=> @click runs after @focusout.

=> @mousedown runs before @focusout.

If you do not want to run the `focusout` function on the input field when the list is clicked at all then you can use `@mousedown.prevent="selecteds(list)"`.

See example below (click on "Full page" so the console.log doesn't block the list):

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        searchText: '',
        listShow: true,
        newDiv:false,
        searcList:[],
        list: {}
    },
   
    methods: {
        inputOutClick() {
        console.log("inputOutClick");
          if (this.listShow == false) {
            console.log("mousedown was fired first");
          }
          this.listShow = false
        },
        selecteds(list) {
        console.log("selecteds");
            this.listShow = false;
            this.searchText = list.name;
        },
        
        async search() {
        console.log("search");
            this.listShow = true;
            this.searcList = ['aeaeg', 'tdthtdht', 'srgsr'];
            this.list.name = "TEST"
        }

    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                v-model="searchText"
                @keyup="search"
                v-on:focusout="inputOutClick"
                />
            <div v-if="listShow" style="background:red">
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="(list, index) in searcList">
                        <a @mousedown="selecteds(list)">LIST TEXT</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
           <div v-if="newDiv">
           <p>hello</p>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```